# Copy files and folders to Nexus 7 from Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, mtp

when I connect my Nexus 7 to my Kubuntu laptop it shows up as a camera instead of a drive. I am running Kubuntu 12.10 and am fully up to date with my Nexus7.i would like to copy files over to it. On my Mac I use the Android file manager app to perform this but would like to be able to copy from my laptop to my Nexus.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help here. kio-mtp has been packaged for Kubuntu and is available in the Experimental PPA: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/experimental for those willing to use it.

Simply sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/experimental then do a sudo apt-get update and then finally sudo apt-get install kio-mtp

When you plugin your device, the system will recongize it and display an option to connect to the device.

Once you open up the device it will show as "Portable Media Player" and also the kio-slave mtp will be available.

Thanks to Rohan Garg for packaging this up.  DOn't know when it will land in the normal repository, but it is working fine for me and several others.

Jonathan

Answer (score 3):

I provide here two very acceptable workarounds. Trying to make mtp work for my N7 seriously broke my OS.

### Through USB with adb (command line)

`adb` is **a**ndroid **d**e**b**ug tool. It lets you access your android device through the command line. You don't need root (though it doesn't hurt).

- install adb

  ```
  sudo apt-get install adb
  ```
- Enable usb debugging on android

In order to get access to the developer options, go in 'settings > about tablet' and tap 7 times on the 'build number' field. Then come back to the 'settings' and you will have a new 'developer options' field. Go in there and enable *USB debugging*.

- Move files around.

From your terminal:

```
adb push ~/Documents/example /sdcard/Ubuntufiles/
```

Will move a file called 'example' from your Document folder in your Ubuntu Home to the folder 'Ubuntufiles' on your N7's 'sdcard'.

- Bonus mode

Using the following command from Ubuntu:

```
adb shell
```

you get a remote terminal to your N7, where you can do stuff the GNU way.

### Wireless, GUI

This might be off-topic, but if your aim is to move files between your computer and your N7, then the USB prerequisite might not be needed. As long as your N7 and your computer are connected to the same router.

- Download an app that creates an FTP server on your N7.

People seem to love 'software data cable', but it really sends you a barrage of apps. 'File expert' is a file browser that doubles as FTP server, SSH server and plenty of other cool stuff. So that's what I use.

- Activate the FTP server on your N7.

On 'software data cable', there's a huge 'start service' button (brace yourself for fullscreen ads). On 'file expert' : My tools > Share content > Share via FTP

It will show you the IP address and the connection creds you need to feed to Ubuntu.

- Connect to N7 from Nautilus on Ubuntu

Nautilus is your file browser.

You need to only do that once. In the future, you'll have a shortcut in Nautilus.

File > Connect to server. A little window shows up that asks you for the very information that your android app is displaying. Input them and hit 'Connect'.

There you are. A file browser window with the content of your N7. Move files around to your heart's content.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer to this.  Sorry that it was so hard to get working in Ubuntu.  Running Kubuntu all I had to do was install the libmtp in the PPA and connect and things worked.  Hopefully your answer helps someone running Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

**mtp - KDE 4.9**

You could try with the mtp-tools (package). At here, the easiest way with the "older" (K)ubuntus & Android is to use an external memory card.

**mtp - KDE 4.10**

The KDE 4.10 is having the kio-mtp /1, 2/ support. At here the kio-mtp seems to work with the Kubuntu Raring (early development version) - KDE 4.10 beta1 /3/

**Links**

1. http://www.afiestas.org/workspaces-gain-mtp-support/
2. http://freininghaus.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/on-the-way-to-dolphin-2-2/
3. http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61111-KDE-SC-4-10-Beta1

Answer (score 0):

Nexus and modern androids can not impersonate flash drives as old ones did. Instead they use MTP protocol. Find yourselv some MTP-aware software.